# Git how to push from branch A to branch B using the branch A?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a script that make someone actions and at the end do :

```
docker build -t gitlab-lab:5005/x/mgmt-docker-gui:lab .
docker push gitlab-lab:5005/x/mgmt-docker-gui:lab
```

In this gitlab I have a project `mgmt-docker-gui` with some branchs ( `lab+lab`, `b`, ...)

I'm on the branch `b` and I run this script, the output is like the git push has been done :

```
The push refers to a repository [gitlab-lab:5005/x/mgmt-docker-gui]
1c19d1598c14: Pushed
c06dbf01f57f: Pushed
abdb447e4874: Pushed
86bd74ce1e22: Pushed
b76fe1e5a82d: Layer already exists
17a14c2cae9e: Layer already exists
9ca9ce532e9e: Layer already exists
011b303988d2: Layer already exists
lab: digest: sha256:6e94909fd0572de54411e1a041d11719aa7fbcde58fc0456bb965ae211e46b20 size: 2004
```

but when I look the file his date is from 2 days ago...

Do I need to be on the branch `lab+lab` to push on this one ?

Comment: docker registry is independent from git branches.

Comment: @JakubKania so it should push on `lab+lab` even if i'm on branch `b` right ?

Comment: And it seems it did, are you sure the resulting container is not identical to the one you had before?

Comment: @JakubKania yes I was using the wrong one everything is working fine. Should I delete the question ?